# signalR get GetHttpContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying to do what's done [here](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/4692934):

```
// Get the HttpContext from the SignalR request
var context = Context.Request.GetHttpContext();
```

(that is to use httpcontext for reading only)

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

1) on event changed call SendMessage method in a hub

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    ActionManager.refreshStatusChanged += this.SendMessage;
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

2) SendMessage calls a web service (that may take a few seconds) and send response via signalR.

```
public void SendMessage(object sender, ActionItemArgs e)
{
     var context = this.Context.Request.GetHttpContext(); // THIS WORKS RANDOMLY!!
     // USE CONTEXT FOR SOME OTHER STUFF

     // send response to clients
     this.Clients.Client(e.ConnectionId).actionInit(false, e);
}
```

-Is this right way of doing it? Should I use a task instead, if so will I still have access to this.Context.Request.GetHttpContext()??

-this.Context.Request.GetHttpContext() - This is what I see once in a while (this happens rarely) but it does happen, resulting in null reference exception (bunch of these properties are null):

[image]

Comment: Try updating to the latest version of SignalR.

Comment: David, can you please see my edit above. thanks